# Problems with ADODB connection in VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, adodb

I have a VB.NET function that I want to connect to use to connect to a SQL Server database and return a recordset. I am new to VB and to SQL, so I hope it is something simple, but I am sure that my connection string and SQL query are correct, as they were checked by a teammate. I have a copy of the Exception message following the code

```
' Retrieve Record Set 
Private Function GetRecords() As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    With conn
        .ConnectionString = "Server=12.345.678.9;Database=db01;User Id=userid01;Password=passwordyword"
        .Open() ' Exception Thrown Here
        rs.Open("SELECT * FROM [Table] ;", "sql")
        rs.Close()
        .Close()
    End With
    Return rs
End Function
```

Exception Message:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in ThisProject.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In your connection string, you have to provide which driver are you using? for example, oledb, oracleoledb.. etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here you try.

```
m_sConnStr = "Provider='SQLOLEDB';Data Source='MySqlServer';" & _ 
 "Initial Catalog='Northwind';Integrated Security='SSPI';"
```

[Connection String for VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821690%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Note that the connection also needs passed in the rs.Open

```
Private Function GetRecords() As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    With conn
        .ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=12.345.678.9;Database=db01;Uid=userid01;Pwd=passwordyword;"
        .Open() ' Exception Thrown Here
        rs.Open("SELECT * FROM [Table] ;", conn)
        rs.Close()
        .Close()
    End With
    Return rs
End Function
```